# How would I change the content overflow of an element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**What I am trying to do?**

I have created a custom footer for my textarea. And want to alter the content overflow of my textarea. So that the text would never go beyond the footer of my textarea.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/65V0Y.jpg

As you can see in the picture the text goes beyond the footer (that horizontal line is where the footer starts) of my textarea. How would I prevent it ? so that the text starts to overflow before it reaches the footer.

**My code:**

```css
#message textarea {
  resize: none;
  min-height: 250px;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#sendMsg #separator hr {
  margin-top: -35px;
}

#sendMsg #contactFormBtn,
#showContactErrMsg {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

#sendMsg #showContactErrMsg {
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#showContactErrMsg {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: maroon;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row" id="message">
  <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="formLabel"><i class="fa fa-sticky-note-o"></i> Message </label>
      <textarea class="form-control" class="formInput" id='inputContactMsg'></textarea>
      <div class="row" id='sendMsg'>
        <div class="row" id='separator'>
          <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
            <hr style="height: 0.5px; background-color: silver;">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <strong id='showContactErrMsg'></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button type="submit" id='contactFormBtn'>Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change below code in `#message textarea`

```
max-height: 250px; /*max instead of min*/
overflow: auto;/*scroll or auto instead of hidden*/
```

This will force your textarea to take scroll once height reaches your set value.

Hope this helps :)

```css
#message textarea { 
  resize: none; 
  max-height: 250px; /*change this to max*/
  padding-bottom: 45px; 
  overflow: auto;/*change this to scroll*/
    height: 90px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
 
#message textarea:focus{
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

#sendMsg #separator hr { 
  margin-top: -35px; 
}

#sendMsg #contactFormBtn, #showContactErrMsg { 
  position: absolute; 
  margin-top: -30px; 
}

#sendMsg #showContactErrMsg { 
  padding-left: 40px; 
  font-size: 12px;
}

#showContactErrMsg { 
  font-size: 14px; 
  color: maroon; 
  font-family: "Century Gothic"; 
}
  
div .extra {
  height: 130px;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row" id="message">
  <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="formLabel"><i class="fa fa-sticky-note-o"></i> Message         </label>
      <div class="extra form-control">
        <textarea class="" class="formInput" id='inputContactMsg'></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="row" id='sendMsg'>
      <div class="row" id='separator'>
      <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
        <hr style="height: 0.5px; background-color: silver;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <strong id='showContactErrMsg'></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <button type="submit" id='contactFormBtn'>Send</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Added textarea into one div and gave class="extra" to it.

Comment: That does not work. I don't think you get me. I edited my Question have a look.

Comment: @Ahtisham I have updated my answer. Took textarea into one div and added some css to it.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I want. Thanks again.

Comment: One last thing. I don't want to get rid of that outline.How would I apply the bootstrap default focus blue outline ?

Comment: Final fixed eveything. Thanks again for your help. :)

Comment: @Ahtisham glad to help you. did you apply blue outline? what css you used? I would like to know :)

Comment: I simply open bootstrap.css file & searched for `form-control` class in it. And copyed the css properties & pasted them in focusin & focusout event of jQuery respectively. As simple as that ;)